# Is useMemo more right way to memoize element in React rather than React.memo?

Tags: reactjs

I was watching youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7RNVYaRS3E (the minute 6:04) and came across the case when the author showed the below code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEmqP.png) and said that wrapping a React component with React.memo does the memoization in a wrong way and suggested to use useMemo for Child component if we really want to memoize the component which made me confused. I tried to use React.memo and it memoized the component accordingly thus I cannot get why the author considers React.memo for a component as incorrect. Can you please explain?

I tried to check if React.memo memoizes the component and it works correctly

Comment: Please include enough information **in** the question that it can be answered, don't rely on off-site links. Links rot, making the question nonsensical. Questions must stand alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: `React.memo` is a useful tool, but it only works if the props don't change. The video is pointing out a case where the props change but you might not realize it.

---

That portion of the video is talking about a specific case, where you pass an element to another component:

```
const Component = () => {
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
  }, []);
  return (
    <MemoItem onClick={onClick}>
      <MemoChild />
    </MemoChild>
  )
}
```

`<MemoChild />` is being passed into the `children` prop of MemoItem. The problem with this is that a JSX tag like `<MemoChild> />` actually is a shorthand for creating a small object describing what you want to put on the page. That object looks roughly like this:

```
{
  type: MemoChild,
  props: null
}
```

Every time Component renders, a brand new object is created describing the memoChild. The object looks very similar, but it's a new object. MemoItem is using React.memo to skip rendering, but this will only work if its props don't change. `onClick` doesn't change because they've wrapped it in `useCallback`, but `children` will change on every render and that will break MemoItem's memoization.